# How to combine new changes with previous commit in git

Tags: git

I made a commit A and now have additional changes that if I committed would give me two commits A & B.

What is the most efficient way to combine the new changes with the ones from the previous commit so that I end up with just one commit?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

`git add -u && git commit --amend`

This will stage all local changes and then use them to rewrite the previous commit. Note that if you've already pushed the previous commit then this is a really bad idea.

Answer (score 1):

If you haven't committed the second set of changes yet, do what Kevin said. If you have, use `git rebase -i` to squash them together.

Comment: Is there a non-interactive way to do this quickly? I guess `git reset HEAD^; git commit --amend` might do it.